# How to use codeigniter helpers files in core php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

Currently I'm working on a project using server, file caching . During the development of this site I have a problem. I can't access codeigniter helpers file in core.php

Folder structure :

```
/Project_folder
    /system files
    /application files
         /helpers
            /cache_helper
    index.php
    static.php (core php file)
```

I want to access `cache_helper.php` in `static.php`. while I am accessing, I get errors like

> **Call to undefined function get_instance()**

Comment: how did u try to include that file??? show us that line of code

Comment: Just add line in core php 
include_once('application files/helpers/cache_helper.php');

Comment: do u have spaces in folder names???

Comment: There is No space for folder name. i'm geting error on $CI =& get_instance(); these line

Comment: @UmaSelvam Try the answer i have given below.

Comment: @Harigovind  I'm trying to access helpers files outside CI application directory. hence your code didn't work anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to include by referencing from root folder.

```
include_once('/Project_folder/system_files/application_files/helpers/cache_helper.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load helper files like this.

> $this->load->helper('helper name');

codeigniter checks the application/helpers directory first and if the helper is not found then it checks system/helpers directory.

For your specific case try loading your helper like this

> $this->load->helper('cache');

[Check this for info regarding helpers](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Write the below line before accessing anything related to CI framework in your core file.

```php
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```